# close as adverb?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, adjectives, adverbs, parts-of-speech

[image]

I looked up in dictionary for the usage of close (which means *near*), and they said that close is adj. But I think that *close* in the highlighted sentence should be adv. Is that right? And *close* in the sentence below should be adv. too.

> She stood close to the exit so that it would be easy to leave at the end of the concert.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Consider if your question suits our [ell.se] site better.

Answer (score 2):

The verb *leave* can take an object complement. Consider the following:

> He left her happy.

Happy is an adjective describing her.

> He left her happily.

Here, happily is an adverb describing how he left her (more specifically, it describes his emotions when he left her).

> He left her close to tears.

Here, *close to tears* is an adjectival phrase describing her. If it was an adverbial phrase, he would be the one close to tears.

Answer (score 0):

Can't the sentence be interpreted two ways? For me it is hard to tell out of context. Does it mean he was close to tears when he left her?  In that case, in the original sentence, close modifies the verb so it is an adverb. OR does it mean she was close to tears when he left. In that case it modifies the subject, so it is an adjective.